# Magento 2: How to create new customer cart via rest API?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I want to place an order for a customer from [API](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#/). Currently, I do:

1. Login as integration (OAuth).
2. Create customer
3. Create customer cart (or take an existing one).
4. Remove all items from the cart.
5. Add items to the cart.
6. Place order.

A customer may have only 1 active cart. I must use the customer cart from Magento and remove the customer's products from his cart. This is not good.

How can I use the cart without touching an existing customer cart?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you add items by posting to

```
[POST] /rest/V1/carts/mine/items
```

But you can also post to a specific cart id

```
[POST] /rest/V1/carts/{{cart-id}}/items
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Yes, I can. But I would like to work with more user cart.

Comment: I guess i fail to understand what you want to do..

Comment: Currently we have 1 user = 1 cart, I want to have 1 user = n carts.

Comment: Perhaps you could use wishlist instead?

Comment: Unfortunately no.
I'm developing a system with a creation of order and I need to work with a cart.

I know the other way, but it is very complicated. If you're wondering [devdocs.magento.com](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html) salesOrderRepositoryV1 PUT.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample Code:

```
 if ($customerId) {
                //START create cart
                $apiUrl =$baseUrl."rest/V1/customers/".$customerId."/carts";
                $quoteId = $this->curlCall($apiUrl, '', 'POST', $setHaders);
                //END create cart

               //START add product to cart
                $productArray = array(
                    "cartItem" => array(
                        "sku" => $skuToAddToCart,
                        "qty" => $rawDataArr['qty'],
                        "quote_id" => $quoteId,
                        "product_option" => array(
                            "extension_attributes" => $productOptions
                        )
                    )
                );
                $preparedPost = str_replace('\"', '', json_encode($productArray));
                $apiUrl = $baseUrl."rest/V1/carts/$quoteId/items";
                $this->curlCall($apiUrl, $preparedPost, 'POST', $setHaders);
                //END add product to cart

                //START add shipping address to cart
                $preparedPost = str_replace('\"', '', $shippingAddressJSON);
                $apiUrl = $baseUrl.'rest/V1/carts/'.$quoteId.'/shipping-information';
                $this->curlCall($apiUrl, $preparedPost, 'POST', $setHaders);
                //END add shipping address to cart

                //START place order
                $preparedPost = str_replace('\"', '', $paymentMethodJSON);
                $apiUrl = $baseUrl.'rest/V1/carts/'.$quoteId.'/order';
                $orderId = $this->curlCall($apiUrl, $preparedPost, 'PUT', $setHaders);
                //END place order
            }
```

Comment: Hi @vishal ! Did you find a solution?

Comment: @where I have used above script to create cart for customer.